# About Euclid's Algorithm proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Reading Lecture 5 [here](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/compsec/Lectures.html) I found this proof for the long division remainder-based Euclid's GCD algorithm (page 20):

> Given any two non-negative integers $a$ and $b$, we can obviously write $a = q·b +r$ for some non-negative quotient integer $q$ and some non-negative remainder integer $r$.
>
> It follows directly from the form $a = q·b + r$ that **every common divisor** of $a$ and $b$ must also divide the remainder $r$.
>
> [...]

Why is it that every common divisor of $a$ and $b$ must also divide the remainder $r$? I can't understand it.

Comment: BTW, that proof is awfully gappy. "We can obviously write" follows by chosing $q=0$ and $r=a$, which does not help us in any wy for the algorithm. The crucial step is that $0\le r<b$ can be quaranteed! This is an important property of the ring of integers that may not apply to other rings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$, say $a=da'$ and $b=db'$, then 
$$ r = a-qb=da'-qdb'=d\cdot(a'-qb').$$

Comment: Simple, nice. It makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It $t$ divides $a$ and $b$, then $t$ divides $a-qb$. But $a-qb=r$.

If you need full detail, let $a=ta'$ and $b=tb'$. Then $a-qb=t(a'-qb')$. So $t$ divides $a-qb$.

**Remark:** The calculation above holds whenever there is a decent notion of divisibility.

One should not underestimate the difficulty of the assertion that if $b$ is positive, there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $a=qb+r$ **and** $0\le r\le b-1$. True, it follows fairly quickly from the fact that every non-empty set of non-negative integers has a smallest element, or, equivalently, by induction.

The result about $q$ and $r$ generalizes nicely in only a restricted number of cases. For details, google *Euclidean domain*.

Answer (score 1):

$\rm\begin{array}{rrl}{\bf Hint}\quad d\mid a,b\!\!\!\! &\Rightarrow&\!\!\!\rm a\equiv \,\color{#C00}0,\ b\equiv \,\color{#0A0}0\ \ \,(mod\ d)\\ &\Rightarrow&\!\!\!\! \begin{eqnarray}\rm r &\,=\:&\rm a-q\cdot b\\ &\,\equiv\:&\rm \color{#C00}0 -q\cdot \color{#0A0}0\,\equiv\, 0\ \ (mod\ d)\end{eqnarray}\\ &\Rightarrow&\rm\!\!\! d\mid r \end{array} $